# Qué estoy haciendo mal al tratar de definir la relación entre una propiedad y su valor en Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Intento figurar cual es mi erro, estoy seguro que se debe al planteamiento que estoy tomando y por ello mi resultado no es el correcto, pero al fin, con el código que tengo me pasa 2 de 3 test. alguien me puede ayudar

Implementar la función isAncestor: debe determinar si dado dos nombres de personas las mismas
son parientes o no (La primera debe ser ancestro de la segunda). La función recibira un objeto
que va a representar sólo la parte femenina del "arbol genealogico" familiar y será de la siguiente forma:

```
//const genealogyTree = {
//   "Mona Simpson": [],
//   "Marge Simpson": ["Lisa Simpson", "Maggie Simpson"],
//   "Jacqueline Bouvier": [ "Patty Bouvier", "Marge Simpson", "Selma Bouvier"],
//   "Patty Bouvier": [],
//   "Selma Bouvier": ["Ling Bouvier"],
//   "Edwina": ["Abigail Simpson"],
//   "Lisa Simpson": [],
//   "Maggie Simpson": [],
//   "Ling Bouvier": []
// }
```

Ejemplo:

- Caso que devuelve true --> isAncestor(genealogyTree, "Jacqueline Bouvier", "Maggie Simpson")
- Caso que devuelve false --> isAncestor(genealogyTree, "Jacqueline Bouvier", "Abigail Simpson").

```
    var isAncestor = function(genealogyTree, ancestor, descendant){
      // Tu código aca:
      if (genealogyTree[ancestor] == genealogyTree[descendant['']]){
        return true;
      }else{
       return false;
      }
    };
```

Comment: Deberías incluir más detalles. Casos de prueba, cuál falla, etc. La funcion solo evalua ancestros en la primer generación, si esperas que evalúe hacia arriba la tenés que cambiar.

Comment: Justo eso, puedo hacer que se cumpla la primer condición , o bien se cumplan las ultimas dos,  pero no puedo hacer que  mi código funcione con las 3 condiciones de la prueba. el punto es que no se en que punto estoy mal, eso me hace pensar que todo como estoy planteando la solución del código es la incorrecta

Answer (score 0):

```
var isAncestor = function(genealogyTree, ancestor, descendant){  
  if(genealogyTree.hasOwnProperty(ancestor)){
  if(genealogyTree[ancestor].includes(descendant)) return true;
  for(let elem of genealogyTree[ancestor]){
    if (isAncestor(genealogyTree,elem,descendant)) return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

};

Esta es la forma correcta de resolver el ejercicio.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código: puede que otros miembros de la comunidad no comprendan su funcionamiento, y/o cómo resuelve esto el problema del OP (autor de la pregunta). Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.